# Preloaded audio using PhoneGap for Ipad

Tags: jquery, html, ipad, html5-audio

Here is my Jquery code:

```
   $(".check").on("click", function(){

         if($(this).is(":visible")){
               $('#audio').remove();
               $file=$(this).html(); // "mp3FileName"
               $(this).append('<div id="audio"><audio autoplay="autoplay" src="sounds/'+$file+'.mp3"></audio></div>');
        }

    });
```

This works perfectly. However, on the ipad when the user "touches" the button with class "check" which fires off the audio, there is roughly a 1 to 1.5 second pause before the audio plays. I'm thinking I should preload all my audio files. However, I have no experience with this. I will have roughly 900 audio files that are roughly 10 kilobytes a piece.

What would be the best way to implement this to make the touch fire off the sound without such a long pause?

Answer (score 0):

This error is common to Apple devices , which is big minus for them. As for this delay , try to do what You think in Your question , it will remove this bug. And , there is another reason why is this happening , Apple iPad lowers audio/video quality to make it playable , which is their mistake , today it is normal that each audio/video plays instantly.

Answer (score 0):

One little thing that will help:

```
var evt = ('ontouchstart' in window) ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
$(".check").on(evt, function(){...}
```

There's something like a half second delay on most touch-enabled devices before click events get fired. So without going through all the pain of trying to preload 900 (!!!!) audio files, you can shave some time off by just binding to `touchstart` instead of `click` for touch-enabled devices.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Multi-Shot example](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/api/) (Demo 4g) from [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/)

If you can fit all 900 samples in a single audio file, that is.

It would prevent the overhead from loading and buffering multiple times, as well as the overhead of 900 HTTP requests (which can easily be up to 1kb per sample, which is almost a megabyte in total!)

Also make sure you use the 'ontouchstart' events as decribed in Kevin Ennis answer, that will save you 300ms.

Answer (score 0):

I got around the delay by using the Cordova Media plugin for PhoneGap and playing the file once at zero volume before the user has a chance to click the button:

```
function playAudio(src, preload) {

        // Create Media object from src
        my_media = new Media(src);

        // Play audio
        if (preload === true) {
            my_media.setVolume(0);
        } else {
            my_media.setVolume(1);
        }
        my_media.play();   

}
```